# Using Harrell’s c and Somers’ D to compare models for best fit

Tags: predictive-models

I would be grateful for some input on an analysis I am doing.

I am looking at medical data set. I have to main outcome variables, organ failure and mortality. I have multiple predictor variables. I have generated a cox model.

I want to look at mortality and organ failure during the entire length of admission and at 30 days. If evaluate the same cox model for mortality during the total length of admission vs at 30 days and find a difference in the fit of the data with a Harrell's C or Somers' statistic is this valid. For example is it valid to say " the predictor variables X1 ... X10 have a better fit for evaluating 30 day mortality vs mortality during total admission.

Appreciate the input.

Best
Rob